# How to get a Calendar in DatePicker in WPF

Tags: wpf, calendar, datepicker, components

I need to get reference to a `Calendar` in a `DatePicker` object.

I imagined it to be this easy:

```
DatePicker datePicker = new DatePicker();
Calendar calendar = datePicker.Calendar;
```

but there is no `Calendar` property in `DatePicker`.

Is there any way how to get that reference?

Comment: Why do you have access to the calendar through the code?

Comment: highlighting days in calendar : http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/547627/Highlight-dates-on-a-WPF-Calendar

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
private void Window_ContentRendered(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Find the Popup in template
    Popup MyPopup = FindChild<Popup>(MyDatePicker, "PART_Popup");

    // Get Calendar in child of Popup
    Calendar MyCalendar = (Calendar)MyPopup.Child;

    // For test
    MyCalendar.BlackoutDates.Add(new CalendarDateRange(
            new DateTime(2013, 8, 1),
            new DateTime(2013, 8, 10)
    ));
}
```

**`Note:`** Always use `FindChild` only when the control will be fully loaded, otherwise it will not find it and give *null*. In this case, I put this code in the event `ContentRendered` of `Window` which says that all the contents of the window successfully load.

Listing of  `FindChild<>`:

```
    public static T FindChild<T>(DependencyObject parent, string childName) where T : DependencyObject
    {
        if (parent == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        T foundChild = null;

        int childrenCount = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent);

        for (int i = 0; i < childrenCount; i++)
        {
            var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);
            T childType = child as T;

            if (childType == null)
            {
                foundChild = FindChild<T>(child, childName);

                if (foundChild != null) break;
            }
            else
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(childName))
                {
                    var frameworkElement = child as FrameworkElement;

                    if (frameworkElement != null && frameworkElement.Name == childName)
                    {
                        foundChild = (T)child;
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        foundChild = FindChild<T>(child, childName);

                        if (foundChild != null)
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    foundChild = (T)child;
                    break;
                }
        }

        return foundChild;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
Popup popup = Template.FindName("PART_Popup", this) as Popup;

_calendar = (Calendar)popup.Child;
```